# How to search for evidence of Camfecting (webcam hacking) on MB?

Tags: macos, network, security, privacy, webcam

I'm worried about camfecting (webcam hacking). The built-in camera light on my macbook (running OSX) is not on, but it isn't hard wired so that doesn't say a lot.

Can I watch outbound traffic in activity monitor to detect data egress (live streaming seems most likely when camfecting is in progress)?

Comment: I read the comments on the posted answer. If you're really that paranoid just put duct tape or something over the camera.

Comment: It's impossible (there is no known way) on all current MacBooks to activate the iSight camera without alerting the user. btw this question is answered already numerous times here.

Answer (score 3):

Objective See has an application that continuously monitors webcam and microphone activity called OverSight. It throws up a notification if either become active and has worked well for me.

Note: the developers rightly warn that this software may not catch all malicious use of the webcam or microphone.

https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html

Answer (score 1):

It is "hard"wired... the firmware of the webcam has this behavior built in. To hack this one would need to rewrite the camera firmware to disable it.

There is very little chance of this actually happening to you. Apple does not document on how to do this, and the actually firmware is probably encrypted.

You seem to be unable to find evidence of this, but got you started on your search in the first place? Lack of evidence would mean this did not take place, yet you are searching anyway?

Article on the subject:
https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/36569/camera.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is [not hard wired](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/36569/camera.pdf) and likely hackers/ratters are able to do this. From what I read in the media camfecting has become increasingly popular with several techniques to break into systems. I would like to for example see where my camera may be working for, e.g. for which software/processes.

Comment: Your link: "Disabling the indicator LED on the iSight entails two requirements. First, as described in Section III, the indicator LED is directly connected to the STANDBY pin on the image sensor. In order to disable the LED, we need to keep STANDBY asserted. Since asserting STANDBY will disable the image sensor output, we need to configure the image sensor to ignore STANDBY before we assert this signal. Second, we need a way to modify the firmware on the EZ-USB to in order to configure the image sensor appropriately as well as keep STANDBY asserted whenever we want the LED to stay off."

Comment: Then "One approach to change the firmware on the camera is to modify the AppleUSBVideoSupport driver to contain different firmware. A second approach would be to provide a new driver that matches the VID/PID and provides a higher probe score [3]. The new driver would run at system start up instead of Apple’s driver and download the new firmware to the camera."

Comment: Then: "These approaches have two major drawbacks. The first drawback is that they rely on programming the iSight when it is in its unprogrammed state which only happens when the camera is first powered by the USB bus. The second drawback is that root access is required in order to modify the existing driver or load a new driver."

Comment: These all conclude that this is not easy to do. Then he goes in and proposes a THIRD alternative: "A third approach overcomes both drawbacks by letting the iSight be programmed with the legitimate firmware when it is first powered. Once the firmware has been loaded onto the camera, it can be reprogrammed at any time using “Firmware Load” vendor-specific USB device requests. Furthermore, it can be reprogrammed from any user space process."

Comment: This basically means that he will modify the firmware and flash it to ALLOW hacking unnoticed. His third method just bypasses the problems of the first two by ignoring them. Essentially he consciously flashes his own camera to allow for a method to bypass the previous two problems.
So for a "hacker" to actually do this, he would need physical access to the laptop TWICE, the root(administrator) password and information about the laptop itself. He also uses an older mac from 2008, newer ones surely are harder to do...

Comment: As I said this is not "easy" to do, unless you are the target of some resourceful group with access to your house and passwords.

Comment: Also to remove this behavior one only needs to install OS X over the old installation... This hack only lasts until a newer version is released.

Comment: Remember that the root password can be obtained by a keylogger if the computer is already hacked. However you may be right that then it's still not easy to do. But by this day there may be software developed. Anyway the [NSA](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/factsheets/macosx_hardening_tips.pdf) recommended/suggested physical removal of the camera...